# Catch vector.erase()

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

When I try to erase elements, from vector and catch it, program stops with code `-1073741819`. This is my code:

```
try {
    vec.erase(it); //it is invalid iterator 
} catch (...) {
    cout << "caught"
}
```

I don't see *caught* in console.
Is there some way to catch exceptions in `vector.erase()` and why my code does not work?

Comment: `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` which means Access Violation on MS Windows.

Comment: Yes, I know, this info provided me debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of attempting to erase an invalid iterator from a `std::vector` is *undefined*.

Assuming an exception is thrown in such circumstances (and therefore catchable) is a common misconception.

Comment: The logic behind this decision goes something like this: Checking for invalid iterators takes time. Because a correct program does not access invalid iterators, checking would be an unnecessary performance penalty for all correct programs. Because outside of test programs such as the one in the question one no one intends to write an incorrect program, typically no checks are made. The behaviour is left undefined by the C++ Standard, so an implementation is allowed to insert checking and some do for debug libraries where error checking is more important than raw speed. Most don't.